# Fatal error: 'QuickTime/QuickTime.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, macos, installation, macos-sierra, allegro

I updated my macOS to Sierra, and some of my files vanished. The most important were Allegro's library. I am trying to install it again like the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJtmJfWNTJY) which I saw the first time which I installed, but the follow error message has been showing:

```
'$Users/macbookpro/Downloads/allegro/include/allegro5/platform/alosx.h:43:12: fatal error: 
      'QuickTime/QuickTime.h' file not found'
  #import <QuickTime/QuickTime.h>
```

I searched for it and I discovered that is just change parameters in Xcode, however, I am not using Xcode to compile my code, although terminal. Any hint?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem build a project with cmake/make instead of xcode..

Comment: No, I didn`t. I had to work with Ubuntu and VM to compile my Allegro code. There are some questions about it in some blogs if you search for this error, but there are not anything detailed which can solve it.

Comment: I get the same error trying to compile allegro 4.2.1 and 4.4.2 on Sierra (using cmake). I know the code is completely rewritten, but that include in that file seems to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of projects out there experiencing this problem, due to Apple's habit of deprecating commonly used libraries. You are not the only one having this issue. See links below. You could copy paste the deprecated SDK's into Xcode as a workaround. Or edit your code to use AVFoundation.framework instead. [See Apple's table on deprecated frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemFrameworks/SystemFrameworks.html).

[Xcode 8/macOS 10.12 removed QtKit support](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues/5264)

[QuickTime/QuickTime.h: file not found](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/quicktime-quicktime-h-file-not-found/24494/2)

Here is a workaround explained:

[Solved: macOS Sierra, Xcode 8, missing quicktime.h](https://sdk.steinberg.net/viewtopic.php?t=229)